# Nginx very slow and sometimes not reachable

Tags: nginx

We are running a Nginx Server but it is very slow and sometimes not even reachable. Sometimes it loads 20 seconds.

This is our config:

```
#Example Config

user www-data;

worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;


events {
    
    worker_connections 4000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    access_log off;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;


    gzip on;

    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable msie6;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;

    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # request timed out -- default 60
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 2;

    # server will close connection after this time -- default 75
    keepalive_timeout 30;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    


    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        #listen 80 http2;
        server_name ***;
        root /**/**/**/;

        # SSL certificate
        ssl_certificate /**/**/**;
        ssl_certificate_key /**/**/**;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
     if (!-f $request_filename){
         set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }   
    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }   
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
    }   

        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
 
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
server_tokens off;
}
```

We also have multiple errors in the nginx/error.log:
`2021/07/01 10:53:28 [error] 25453#25453: *81 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,`
The errors are POST and GET requests.

Don't know if it has something to do with it.

Is there anything we can do?

Thanks in Advance!